# Java Spring REST, value from object (POST)

Tags: spring, rest, object

I have a quick question. I`m sending two params in a json object (user) from angular to my spring app using POST. When I display this object it is:

```
System.out.println(user.email);
{email=example@example.com, password=gfdgdfgf}
```

In Java my code is:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/userLogin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public boolean userLogin(@RequestBody Object user, ModelMap model) {
...
}
```

But when I try to display the field from this object like:
`user.password`, it doesn`t work.

Many thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You are mapping your data to an Object, which lacks the needed fields(email and password). You should create an entity class and use it instead. Jackson should be able to map your passed parameters.

```
public class User{
    public String email;
    public String password;
    /* ... */
}
```